# Easy PHP Replace

Tags: php, preg-replace

I want the first word of the string to be surrounded by  tags. Insted with my code all the words gets surrounded by it.

The code is for a wordpress so the_title is the title of the post. Eg. Hello World.
I want it to be `<span>Hello </span>World`.

```
<?php
$string = the_title('', '', false);
$pattern = '^(\S+?)(?:\s|$)^';
$replacement = '<span>$1</span>';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
?>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?=$string?></a></h2>
```

Sorry for my bad english :)

**MY SOLUTION:**

```
<?php
$string = the_title('', '', false);
$pattern = '/\S+/';
$replacement = '<span>$0</span>';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string, 1);
?>

            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?=$string?></a></h2>
```

Comment: May i ask why you're using preg_replace and not a simple substr/explode operation? Am I missing something with what you need to extract?

Comment: I don't know other ways to do it. I searched a long time and found a jquery script and just took the pattern from it and got it into a php script instead.

Comment: Don't edit the question title to mark it as "Solved". Select a best answer instead! (Click the checkmark next to the best answer).

Comment: It said i had to wait like 8 minutes and i dont wanna waist other peoples time when its solved. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try limiting the number of replacements to `1` by passing `1` as the 4th argument to `preg_replace` as:

```
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string,1);
                                                      ^^
```

A better regex to find words would be using word boundaries:

```
$pattern = '/\b(\w+)\b/';
```

but this way you'll have to restrict the replacement to `1` again.

Alternatively you can just match the first word as:

```
$pattern = '/^\W*\b(\w+)\b/';
```

and just use `preg_replace` without limiting number of replacements.

NOTE:  `\w` = `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` if your word is allowed to have other characters, change suitably. If you consider any non-whitespace as a word character you can use `\S`.

Comment: I changed the pattern to this:

$pattern = '/\S+/';

Answer (score 1):

Use something like the following:

```
$string = "Hello World";
$val = explode(" ", $string);
$replacement = '<span>'.$val[0].' </span>';
for ($i=1; $i < count($val); $i++) {
    $replacement .= $val[$i];
}
echo "$replacement";
```

Comment: You could have done: `$val = explode(' ', $string, 2); $string = '<span>'.$val[0].' </span>'.$val[1];` The third parameter is what makes the difference here.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update the pattern and the replacement like this (this ignores first whitespaces at the beginning):

```
<?php

$string = the_title('', '', false);
$pattern = "^(\\s*)(\\S+)(\\s*)(.*?)$";
$replacement = '<span>$2</span>';
$string = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Answer (score 0):

PCRE is not necessary in this case. You could do the same with a simple `substr`/`strpos` combination (which should, although minimally, be faster):

```
$str = 'Hello World';

$endPos = strpos($str, ' ')+1;
$str = '<span>'.substr($str, 0, $endPos).'</span>'.
       substr($str, $endPos);
echo $str;
```

If you really want to go with the PCRE way, you can do:

```
$str = preg_replace('/^([^\s]+\s)/', '<span>\1</span>', $str);
```

The statement does not require a `$limit`, because the pattern starts with a `^` (beginning of string), which is not a delimiter, unlike yours.

Answer (score 0):

`$string = '"' . substr($string, 0, strpos($string, ' ')) . '"';` ought to do the trick!